# Assign UIButtons Titles of NSMutableArray To UIButtons of NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have Two NSMutableArray .My First Array contain 3 UIButtons along With Buttons Titles and My Second Array contain 50 UIButtons .But all these 50 UIButtons have random alphabet as a Title.here is my first Array code.

```
  NSMutableArray *buttons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:btn1, btn2, btn3, nil];
        [btn1 setTitle:@"stack" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
        [btn2 setTitle:@"over" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
        [btn3 setTitle:@"flow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now i want to Assign my first button title  which is "stack" to second Array buttons using index 3-7 .second button title which is "over"  to Second Array buttons using index 15-18 and Third button title which is "flow" to scond Array buttons using index 30-33. please any one suggest a solution for me.thanx

Comment: Its difficult to understand what exactly you want to do. please elaborate your question.

Comment: Thanx @ mihirios for quick response ..please just check this link here i post question with detail.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596414/put-random-uibuttons-title-of-nsmutablearray-to-uibuttons-of-nsmutablearray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i=3; i<=7; ++i) {
    UIButton *temp = [stack objectAtIndex:i];
    [temp setTitle:@"Temp" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

As an example for one. Now repeat for your other indexes :)

Comment: Thanx @Martol 1ni for quick response.your code solve my Index problem.but if you check this link then i hope you can understand my problem.Thanx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596414/put-random-uibuttons-title-of-nsmutablearray-to-uibuttons-of-nsmutablearray –